# How can i pass a Lazy<T> into my projection?

Tags: linq-to-sql, domain-driven-design, projection, lazy-evaluation

My `Vehicle` type:

```
public class Vehicle : EntityObject
{
    private Lazy<string> _nameFromDelegate = null;
    private Lazy<IList<Component>> _components = null;


    public Vehicle(int id, string name, Lazy<string> nameFromDelegate, Lazy<IList<Component>> components)
        : base(id)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this._nameFromDelegate = nameFromDelegate;
    }


    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public string NameFromDelegate
    {
        get
        {
            return this._nameFromDelegate.Value;
        }
    }

    public IList<Component> Components
    {
        get
        {
            return this._components.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to project my type in L2S using the constructor and pass in certain mappings as delegates so they're evaluated in memory rather than L2S trying to translate them to SQL.

In the example below i'm trying to map the "vehicle.Name" value from SQL onto two properties on my `Vehicle` type: the "Name" `string` property and the "NameFromDelegate" `string` property (which encapsulates the `Lazy<string>`).

I'm hoping to prove that it doesn't make any difference to L2S whether i pass in the "vehicle.Name" to the `string` ctor param or to the `Lazy<string>` ctor param. But perhaps it does:
[image]

I don't understand why there is a need to cast from `string` to `Func<string>`. Ideas?

Stack trace for reference:

```
   at System.Convert.DefaultToType(IConvertible value, Type targetType, IFormatProvider provider)
   at System.String.System.IConvertible.ToType(Type type, IFormatProvider provider)
   at System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider)
   at System.Data.Linq.DBConvert.ChangeType(Object value, Type type)
   at Read_Vehicle(ObjectMaterializer`1 )
   at System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.ObjectReaderCompiler.ObjectReader`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at DelegateQueries.Models.VehicleRepoWithDelegates.GetAll() in %path%\DelegateQueries\Models\VehicleRepoWithDelegates.cs:line 26
   at DelegateQueries.Tests.RepoTests.VehicleRepo_CanReturn_NameFromDelegateProp_InLinq_WithDelegate() in %path%\DelegateQueries\DelegateQueries.Tests\RepoTests.cs:line 31
```

Comment: The projection you are trying to do works when using in memory collection so my guess is that you found a linq 2 sql bug when trying to project to a Func<>.

Comment: I think i see what you're saying now.. i didn't really think i was "projecting to a `Func`". I guess i am in the ctor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to work around the problem:

```
static Lazy<T> Lazyfy<T>(T input)
{
    return new Lazy<T>(() => input);
}

public IQueryable<Vehicle> Vehicles()
{
    return from veh in ctx.vehicles
           select new Vehicle(veh.id, veh.name, Lazyfy(veh.name), null);
}
```

**UPDATE** you can also do this:

```
static Func<T> Functify<T>(T input)
{
    return () => input;
}

public IQueryable<Vehicle> Vehicles()
{
    return from veh in ctx.vehicles
           select new Vehicle(veh.id, veh.name, new Lazy<string>(Functify(veh.name)), null);
}
```

but you can't do this:

```
var r = from veh in ctx.vehicles
                    select new Func<int>(() => veh.id);
r.ToList();
```

It appears that L2S is treating the lambda expression creation as a value assignment, instead as a method call and is trying to convert the value from the db to it. I'm saying it's a bug since this works on linq to objects.

Comment: Why? Why? Why? Why? Please explain it to me.
I tried to use a wrapper before but maybe just didn't get it right? Is it about tricking L2S into not attempting to translate this as an `Expression`?

Comment: @cottsak see my update, the problem is that L2S is trying to create the Func<string> by converting the value from the db instead of treating it like a method call and passing the arg from the db. At least is easy to work around this bug, by explicitly moving the creation of the Func<> to a separate method.

Comment: The linq provider in NHibernate seams to suffer from exactly the same problem.

Comment: Crazy. I think the reason it works to LINQ To Objects is because the expression is not being translated to SQL. I don;t think it's a L2S "bug" per se but simply a failure to translate- only that the "could not be translated to SQL" exception is not the one being raised perhaps because this use case was not forseen??

Comment: You are probably correct that this feature has not been foreseen for the L2S, but since we are talking about a projection, i think that the process of thought should be: determine what we need to select in order to create the projection, find any known bits in the projection expression that can be optimized by sql translation, for unknown bits, just provide the value from the field to the expression.